# How to convert Numpy special syntax to Hy

Tags: python, numpy, hy

I have this Python code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.randn(500, 2)
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1])
```

But I don't know how to convert `X[:,0]` and `X[:,1]`, which I think is a special syntax Numpy created, to Hy. I tried these below, but they did not work.

```
(get X #(: 0))
(get X : 0)
; I want to do `X[:,0]` in Python
```

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do. But this looks fine, just use plt.show() to show it at the end. This code works.

Comment: I want to convert the Python code to Hy programming language. And I'm having trouble converting this particular expression: `X[:,0]`.

Comment: `X[:, 0]` is indexing for a 2d numpy array, one with shape (500,2).  This picks the first of the 2nd dimension, the result will be a (500,) shape.  Does `hy` multidimensional arrays?  I dabbled in it a while back; it's supposed to implmement LISP like behaviour in Python, right.   The 2d array is a bit like a list of lists, 500 lists each with length 2.

Comment: This may be more detailed that what you want but that is plain python syntax, which gets converted into a `X.__getitem__((slice(None), 0))`.  That is the `getitem` is passed a tuple.  Lists would complain about such an index, `numpy` arrays accept and use that kind of tuple.  `numpy` doesn't add special syntax, it just implements a new array oriented class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, NumPy doesn't change Python's syntax; it just has somewhat unusual semantics for indexing. In Python, `X[:,0]` is shorthand for `X[(slice(None), 0)]`. You can translate that literally to Hy as `(get X #((slice None) 0))`. Alternatively, use Hyrule's `ncut`: `(require hyrule [ncut]) (ncut X : 0)`.